# Is positive gossip haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Is it considered haram if you talk GOOD about someone behind their back? Or is backbiting haram in general?

Answer (score 0):

Talking good about someone in their absence is not backbiting.

> Abu Hurairah [radiyallaahu-anhu] narrated that the Messenger of Allaah
> [sallal-laahu-alayhi-wasallam] said, ‘’Do you know what backbiting
> is?’’ They (i.e. the sahaabah) replied Allaah and his Messenger know
> best’’; he said [sallal-laahu-alayhi-wasallam] said, ‘’**It is to
> mention your brother what he dislikes**’’. Someone asked, ‘’What if what
> I said is true?’’ He [sallal-laahu-alayhi-wasallam] replied, ‘’If what
> you said about him is true you have backbitten him, and if it is not
> true you have slandered him’’. [Muslim]

Comment: What if he is extremely humble and dislikes that people speak good about him

Answer (score 0):

You can always talk good about someone in their absence but it should be true and if they hear what you said, they should not dislike it. For example, someone may be spending lot of money in charity and he wants to keep it secret. But if someone find it out, he should not tell it to others because he does not like making this public.